# How to get back distraction-free mode we had before WP 4.1?

Tags: visual-editor

One of the features of WP 4.1 was the introduction of new distraction-free mode.

This is a personal opinion, but I think it's awful, in fact, compared with the pre 4.1 mode:

- it performs a lot worse with editor styles
- it offers less space to write
- it is more distracting, because every time you move mouse you see *things* appear and disappear again.. what's more distracting than movement in the screen?

BTW, purpose of this question isn't give opinion on the feature, but ask how can I get back pre 4.1 distraction-free mode?

I did a research on the web and found a lot of people complaining, but no solutions, aside someone saying only (discouraged) option is downgrading that, of course, isn't an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Edit

As of WP 4.3 this won't work anymore. WP have completely removed the javascript for the *old* distraction-free mode.

To use this in 4.3 versions, get a copy of javascript file [from WP 4.2 release](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/4.2-branch/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpfullscreen) and enqueue it before using code below.

---

You can:

1. use [`'wp_editor_settings'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_editor_settings/) filter to set the `'_content_editor_dfw'` option to false.
2. use [`'mce_buttons'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/mce_buttons/) and [`'teeny_mce_buttons'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/teeny_mce_buttons/) filters to:

   - remove new distraction-free button, that has id: `'dfw'`
   - add the *old* distraction-free button that has the id: `'wp_fullscreen'`
3. use [`'tiny_mce_plugins'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tiny_mce_plugins/) and [`'teeny_mce_plugins'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/teeny_mce_plugins/) filters to add the old plugin script, that luckily wasn't removed, it is named `'wpfullscreen'`

For #1 and #2 you can check that the editor your editing is the one with id `'content'`.

All steps above as a plugin (available as a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/c081ce03a68b00d983d5)):

```
<?php namespace GM\FSDFM;
/**
 * Plugin Name: Fullscreen Distraction-Free Mode (pre v4.1)
 * Plugin URI: https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/c081ce03a68b00d983d5
 * License: MIT
 */

if (!is_admin()) return;

function should($editor_id = 'content') {
  return (version_compare($GLOBALS['wp_version'], '4.1') >= 0)
    && in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('post.php','post-new.php'))
    && $editor_id === 'content';
}

function buttons($buttons, $editor_id) {
  return should($editor_id)
    ? array_diff(array_merge((array) $buttons, array('wp_fullscreen')), array('dfw'))
    : $buttons;
}

function plugins($plugins) {
  return should()
    ? array_diff(array_merge((array) $plugins, array('wpfullscreen')), array('fullscreen'))
    : $plugins;
}

function settings($settings, $editor_id) {
  if (should($editor_id)) {
    $settings['_content_editor_dfw'] = false;
  }
  return $settings;
}

add_filter('wp_editor_settings', __NAMESPACE__.'\\settings', 30, 2);
add_filter('mce_buttons', __NAMESPACE__.'\\buttons', 30, 2);
add_filter('teeny_mce_buttons', __NAMESPACE__.'\\buttons', 30, 2);
add_filter('teeny_mce_plugins', __NAMESPACE__.'\\plugins');
add_filter('tiny_mce_plugins', __NAMESPACE__.'\\plugins');
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I added back the 4.2 javascript and enqueued it at the top of the plugin. The button displays but clicking it does nothing. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong.